# Advice on creating Google Play Store icons for your App

Tags: android, icons, google-play

```
Android Studio 0.4.5
```

Hello,

I have just build my first App and getting ready to upload it to the google play store.

However, I have to create some icon for my App. I am not very good with graphics programming using photoshop, illustrator etc.

Just wondering what other developers use to create their app icons?

Any tip and tricks to creating great looking icons?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below links could be useful.

- http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html
- http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools

Answer (score 1):

There are not too many options to create a good looking icon for your app...

1) Hire the service of a professional Graphic Designer

2) Buy a logo / icon from hundreds of sites that deal with these things

3) There are some websites that offer free icons - if it does not suit you needs you can edit then to your taste.

4) Take a quick "crash course" on the web using tutorials and know-how's using Photoshop and Illustraor - it is really not complicated to design a basic good-looking icon.

5) If you have a friend that is good at drawing art - you can scan the artwork and transform it into icons.

6) Find a friend that DOES know Photoshop and Illustrator :-)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The Android Asset Studio is a good place to start. You can try your hand at making an icon from one of the pre-defined modes and it gives you icons for all screen densities. You can also go to the android design community in google plus and try asking for some help over there.http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html